# Which continuous integration framework for Perl?

Tags: perl, testing, continuous-integration

What are the best continuous integration frameworks/projects for Perl and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only one I've seen in action is [Smolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smolder) (it is used for [parrot](http://smolder.plusthree.com/app/public_projects/report_details/5562)). It is TAP based and therefore integrates well with standard perl testing structures. See also this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mpeters/smolder-introduction).

Comment: Doesn't install properly...lots of compilation errors when building.
wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

I've looked into the various ones suggest, but they all seemed a little fiddly to get going.

I've since found [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) , from playing around with it, it seems very nice, coupled with [tap-to-junit-xml](http://jmason.org/software/scripts/tap-to-junit-xml.txt) it took me about 30 minutes to get a basic build happening. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Test-AutoBuild](http://www.autobuild.org/)!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) checkout and run your Perl source. It takes a little googling to piece together how to do it, but I have seen it done before.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but [TAP::Harness::JUnit](http://search.cpan.org/~lkundrak/TAP-Harness-JUnit-0.23/lib/TAP/Harness/JUnit.pm) should make just about any CIS available to you. I like Bamboo, since it integrates into the rest of my (Atlassian) tools.

Answer (score 2):

I've been impressed with [BuildBot](http://buildbot.net) recently - it supports a lot of source control systems, has a nice web interface & IRC bot that work out-of-the-box, is pretty easy to configure, and very extensible (in Python).

It took some time to get it configured/extended for my current project, and I had to jump through some hoops to get it to play nicely with [TAP::Formatter::HTML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TAP-Formatter-HTML).  But now it's up & running I'm glad I spent the time on it - it works quite well.

Wishlist items for me are stats collecttion & display, and integration of TAP.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Smolder :) In fact, it should be very easy to link BuildBot and Smolder together so that Buildbot runs your tests and then submits the TAP Archive to Smolder for stats, collection, display, Atom feeds, email, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pjam - is a new [pinto](https://github.com/thaljef/Pinto) based build server for perl applications. This is the perl specific build server,
because of using **pinto** under the hood it gives you very control on your builds:

- comparing builds
- roll back project to given build
- see changes for the next build
- etc.

It's ruby on rails applications - see more on https://github.com/melezhik/pjam-on-rails. The author.